# How do I keep incremental sequence going on sql from a specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Im trying to figure out SQL statement that could update a sequence from a point.  as you can see it stops at 15 and starts at 19, when in fact 19 should be 16 and 20 should be 17 and so on.

SQL SERVER VERSION 11.0.5058

[image]

Comment: Its done by the application but some how broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily renumber when you query:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by col3)
from table t;
```

If you want to update the numbers, you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by col3) as newcol3
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set col3 = newcol3;
```

However, if the column is an id for the table, then don't change the value.  Discontinuous ids are fine, there is no reason to change the values.  And, if the values are used for foreign key references, changing a value might either break the database or take a long time.

Comment: what if this is a result of a query can I still use the row_number()?  does row_number use the current query's numbering scheme?

Comment: It uses whatever is passed in as the `order by` column.